# g++ outputs filenames with leading space?

Tags: visual-studio-code, g++

I'm building my first c++ program in VS Code via g++, but when I specify a filename for the output executable with the `-o filename.exe` flag, the output files always have a leading space (" filename.exe" rather than just "filename.exe").

I'm just getting started with c++, and I've never used VS Code before (but chose it because it seems like a pretty popular "IDE" for c++ stuff), so bear with me if this is stupid. I'm running this all on Kubuntu 18.04 with the latest version of `build-essential` (12.4ubuntu1) and VS Code (1.30.2).

Based on a little bit of google-fu (and some trial/error), I put together this build task `tasks.json`:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build hello world",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/helloworld.cpp", "-o helloworld.exe"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }

        }
    ]
}
```

When I run this to build my `helloworld.cpp` file (which is exactly what you expect), it outputs an executable file called `' helloworld.exe'`, rather than `helloworld.exe`.

Comment: Thats because you have put `-o` and the filename in a single argument.

Comment: Wow, I am stupid. That's a very simple fix. Just swapped `-o helloworld.exe` to `-o`, `helloworld.exe` and it works now. @tkausl submit that as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are generally two ways to pass to arguments to command line options. The first one is as a single value:

```
<command> -ohelloworld.exe
```

the second is as two values:

```
<command> -o helloworld.exe
```

The parser understands both and they have the same result. Unfortunately in your example, you're not passing *two* values but *one* with a space in it, as there is no shell in between which could split them at the space. So what `gcc` *sees* is literally a single argument with the value `-o helloworld.exe`, and since the `-o` is followed by more characters, `gcc` takes it as the filename, including the leading space. So to fix this, either use the single argument `"ohelloworld.exe"` or split them into two `"-o", "helloworld.exe"`.